# How to debug chrome-native://newtab/ with Chrome Remote Debugging

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I want to debug a web app that I open in Android device Chrome browser. 
I follow this tutorial about [Chrome remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging).

However, by design, my app should open in `chrome-native://newtab/`, not exactly in regular Chrome Search bar. So, `Remote devices` tab in Chrome Devtools looks like this:

[image]

And when I click `Inspect` button to inspect that tab, it opens with nothing:

[image]

How to debug `chrome-native://newtab/`? Is it possible with Chrome Devtools?

Comment: Might be a bug or the lack of implementation in Chrome. Check https://crbug.com for an existing report just in case.

Comment: I was also hoping to do the same - mostly to work out where the "Discover" content comes from as I would like to view it in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to open up a new tab and click the inspect button to start debugging.

In the screenshot you shared, there is a text field to input the URL of the page. Try to input google.com and click the inspect button.

Here is what it looks like when I opened up a new tab:

[image]

Here is how the DevTools window look like when clicked the Inspect menu:

[image]

Try to follow the steps listed on [Get Started with Remote Debugging Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging), it's quite straightforward.

Comment: _click the inspect button_?? What `inspect button`? There is no any `inspect button` in Chrome AFAICT